# How to post some data from multiple form data

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I'm working on an online forum similar to Stack Exchange. I want to implement this functionality:

When I have a list of questions, if I click on some question it directs me to the page with more details about question and answers. But when the page is redirected the last questions ID (primary key)  is posted. I want to post the `Question_ID` of that particular question.

table name: *Questions*
page name: **question.php**

Here is my code:

```
<?php function select_project($table)
{
    global $dbCon;
    $result = mysqli_query($dbCon,"SELECT * FROM questions");

    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($rows>0)
    {
?> 
        <form action="question_detail.php" method="post" name="qForm">
<?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {   
?>
        <div class="container">
        <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="questionid" value="<?php echo $row['Question_ID']; ?>">

            <div class="subject">
            <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write('<a href="question_detail.php" onclick="document.forms[\'qForm\'].submit(); return false;"><?php echo $row['Subject']; ?></a>');
            </script>
            </div>

            <div class="body">
                <p><?php echo $row['body']; ?></p>
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        </div>
<?php       }
?> 
</form>
```

Comment: i dont get you you want to do, seems you are creating a link for each question and that link do a submit of your form. and what else?

Comment: I'm not sure to really understand what your want to do, but I'm sure your have a conception issue. What does `question_detail.php` do exactly ?

Comment: Yes exactly, that link acts like a submit button. There is a hidden data (Question_ID) which I have set for each question and i want that to be posted to directed page. So that i can get that questions ID to retrieve the question from database.

Comment: Why do you echo out javascript to write out your HTML?  This seems like an unnecessary level of complexity

Comment: @ceadreak it recieves posted data from Question.php (where i want to recieve question_ID) to display all the data related to the question. (Subject, body, created date, posted username etc)

Comment: @EatPeanutButter When i click some question from the list i want it to direct me to the Question_details.php and also to POST hidden Question_ID

Comment: See, in Stack Exchange the question list is shown right and when i click specific question it directs you to a detailed page. I want to achieve the same.... Please anyone help...

Comment: You probably want to use a $_GET URL parameter (so users can link directly to questions). In this case, just echo out `'<a href="question_detail.php?question_id="' . $row['question_id'] . '">';` for each question. And scrap the javascript stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by passing question id in the url parameter. As you are not updating or inserting data to database but querying the database, you can use $_GET or $_REGUEST superglobal variable to get the id value in question_detail.php.

```
<?php 
function select_project($table){
    global $dbCon;
    $result = mysqli_query($dbCon,"SELECT * FROM $table");
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($rows>0){ ?>     
<?php   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
        <div class="container">
           <div class="subject">
             <a href="question_detail.php?q_id=<?php echo $row['Project_ID'];?>">
                     <?php echo $row['Subject']; ?></a></div>
            <div class="body">
                <p><?php echo $row['body']; ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php  } //closing while loop
   }//closing if
}//closing function 
?>
```

Using the function:

```
   select_project($table);
```

And in question_detail.php

```
$qid = isset($_GET['q_id'])? $_GET['q_id']:'';
if(!empty($qid)){
//SELECT * FROM questiondetail WHERE question_id='$qid';
}else{
//No question with this id or invalid question id
}
```

Comment: Thanks, actually that's what i was looking for but end of with javascript to POST data (google search). I will check on it...